# Advantage of elasticsearch over grep when trying to search keyword in logs files

Tags: grep, regular-expression, logs, elasticsearch

I know elasticsearch is good for full text search but when it comes to analyze logs, say nginx logs what is the advantage of using it over grep (with tail, awk, etc.) ?

Quite of often I dig through logs try to find some keywords, with grep it is simple. If I use elasticsearch, the investment of setting it up to work and the learning curve are huge compared to grep. So I am wondering is it worth the "trouble" ?

In what scenario grep just can't handle and elasticsearch will shine ?

Answer (score 2):

With `grep`, there is no indexing, so each time you want to search for something, the command needs to read through all the logs. When you have a non-trivial amount of logs, this can take a long time and a lot of CPU power.

With elasticsearch, the messages are indexed as they arrive, so the actual searching can happen faster and with less CPU power. Elasticsearch also includes various analytic functions `grep` cannot do alone.

It's mostly a matter of scale. Basically, if you only have *megabytes* of logs, dealing with them using `grep` and other command line tools is trivial. If you have *gigabytes* of logs, searching through them with `grep` is starting to get slow and inefficient, but doable if you plan ahead. With *terabytes* of logs, you'll definitely need something like Elasticsearch to deal with them in a reasonable way.